# Why do programs sometimes "skip over" printfs?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I have the following code:

```
if (!strcmp(ent_child->d_name, "eeprom")){
    printf("\tread_from_driver: found a match! ");//DEBUG
    get_child_path(child_path, child_path, "eeprom");
    printf("The path is: %s\n", child_path);//DEBUG
    read_eeprom(child_path);
}
```

This causes a segfault at some point, (probably get_child_path), but the first printf never happens, even though when I fix the code to be this:

```
if (!strcmp(ent_child->d_name, "eeprom")){
    while(1)
         printf("\tread_from_driver: found a match! ");//DEBUG
    get_child_path(child_path, child_path, "eeprom");
    printf("The path is: %s\n", child_path);//DEBUG
    read_eeprom(child_path);
}
```

It does happen. What's going on? This is definitely not the first time I observed this behavior.

Comment: Perhaps try flushing the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`stdout` is *line-buffered* by default, which means that you only get updated output when you send a newline character, or when you explicitly call `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: Actually `stdout` is line-buffered or fully buffered by default, depending on whether or not it's an interactive device. If you want to be sure the output arrives at a particular time, always use `fflush`.

Comment: Rather than adding multiple `ffush(stdout)`'s to your code, it might be cleaner to add a single call `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0)` to disable buffering for `printf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\n` in the end of each `printf` to make sure the output is flushed. Otherwise it's buffered and not immediately written.

Answer (score 2):

put `\n` in the end of the first `printf`, the segmentation fault warning eliminates the last output line. I cant really explain it, I just know that if you put a `\n` it is written

Comment: This isn't helpful. It's like saying, "Just do it!"

Answer (score 2):

Only `stderr` is not buffered ... `stdout` is buffered, and therefore you won't necessarily see the output until either the buffer is full, a newline character has been encountered, or you specifically flush the stream.

Therefore, if you're wanting to print debug messages, use `stderr` instead of `stdout`.